# How do I use Cloud Foundry to login to IBM Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to get started using IBM Bluemix and want to use the Cloud Foundry CLI to login and manage my applications.  But I cannot figure out how to login using the cf command.  I think what I am missing is the API endpoint I need to provide for the cf login command:

```
cf login -a [API_URL] -u [USERNAME] -p [PASSWORD]
```

I suspect I use my IBM ID username and password, but I'm not sure about the API_URL.  Seems like this should be an easy question to search, but I have not been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 18):

You set the api endpoint like this:

```
cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
```

and then you login with `cf login`.

Alternatively you can use the European endpoint:

```
cf api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
```

EDIT:

Alternatively, as you were implying, you can pass the API endpoint to `cf login` directly via the `-a` option:

```
cf login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net -u <ibm.com id>
```

Comment: Just want to point out you don't have to be in Europe to use the eu-gb endpoint, you can be anywhere in the world.

Comment: @whitfiea, yes, fair enough, edited response to remove the implication that you had to be in Europe to use eu-gb.

Comment: You may also just enter "cf login" and be prompted by the api, username and password.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer to my question.  The API endpoint for IBM bluemix is https://api.ng.bluemix.net.  That was the key piece of information I was missing to login to IBM Bluemix using the Cloud Foundry CLI:

```
cf login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net -u <IBM ID Name> -p <IBM ID Password>
```

I'm impressed with how easy the rest of the cf command is to manage apps.